# QCompleter::activated disconnected after losing and gaining focus

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I found a strange case which I do not understand. Maybe it is a Qt bug, maybe I am doing something wrong.

A header:

```
// File mylineedit.h
#pragma once

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDebug>

class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QLineEdit(parent) { }

public slots:
    void onCompleterActivated(const QString& text) { qDebug() << "MyLineEdit" << text; }
};
```

And the main source file:

```
// File main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "mylineedit.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QLineEdit* lineEdit1 = new MyLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* lineEdit2 = new MyLineEdit();

    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(&w);
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit1);
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit2);

    lineEdit1->setCompleter(new QCompleter());
    auto model = new QStringListModel(QStringList() << "A" << "B" << "C");
    lineEdit1->completer()->setModel(model);
    QObject::connect(lineEdit1->completer(), SIGNAL(activated(QString)), lineEdit1, SLOT(onCompleterActivated(QString)));

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Once you run this, you can get a completer with values "A", "B", "C" in the first line edit. When you select any of these values, it will print the message to the console. This is correct. But then change focus to the other line edit and then back. Try picking "A", "B", "C" again. No message is printed out, the signal/slot seems disconnected. Any ideas?

Tested with MinGW 5.3.0 and MSVC 2015 using with Qt 5.9.2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified your sample slightly and tried to reproduce the behavior you described but I couldn't:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version: " << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // main application
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWin;
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QLineEdit qEdit1;
  qVBox.addWidget(&qEdit1);
  QCompleter qCompl1;
  QStringListModel qComplModel(QStringList() << "A" << "B" << "C");
  qCompl1.setModel(&qComplModel);
  qEdit1.setCompleter(&qCompl1);
  QLineEdit qEdit2;
  qVBox.addWidget(&qEdit2);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qCompl1,
    static_cast<void(QCompleter::*)(const QString&)>(
      &QCompleter::activated),
    [](const QString &text)
    {
      qDebug() << "Activated: " << text;
    });
  // run-time loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The significant differences in my sample:

1. I used Qt5 style signal handlers (as I'm used to).
2. I didn't `new` the Qt widgets (as I'm used to when I write minimal samples).

For me, it's hard to believe that one of these changes makes your described issue unbroken.

I compiled and tested with VS2013, Qt 5.9.2 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: snapshot of testQCompleter]

I did the following interactions:

- click in `qEdit1`
- type `A` and click on item `A` in the popup menu

Output:

```
Activated:  "A"
```

I continued with:

- click in `qEdit2`
- type `B`
- click in `qEdit1`
- erase text, type `B`, and click on item `B` in the popup menu

Output:

```
Activated:  "B"
```

It works like expected.

---

After some conversation, I had a look at woboq.org in the source code of [`QLineEdit`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp.html):

The interesting part is in [QLineEdit::focusOutEvent](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp.html#_ZN9QLineEdit13focusOutEventEP11QFocusEvent):

```
if (d->control->completer()) {
    QObject::disconnect(d->control->completer(), 0, this, 0);
}
```

If I read this right, all signal handlers of `QLineEdit` (emitted by the set completer) are disconnected. I believe this is the reason for the observed issue. (Therefore, it works for lambdas and methods of other classes.)

Comment: @V Could you try my sample on your side? (Just out of curiosity...)

Comment: It seems that the problem is only when I subclass the `QLineEdit`, i.e. when the called slot is a method of the object to which the completer is attached. When I connect to any other slot (e.g. a main window's method or a lambda), I do not observe the error. I also tested the new style of connection signal/slot and it is the same as is my example.

Comment: @V.K. It sounds like a bug in Qt. My last idea: In the Qt doc. sample of  [QCompleter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#details), they give it a parent instance. You may set your `MyLineEdit` instance set as parent of the associated completer. No idea, whether this helps...

Comment: @V.K. I just had a look at woboq: [QLineEdit::focusOutEvent](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp.html#_ZN9QLineEdit13focusOutEventEP11QFocusEvent). Notice the `QObject::disconnect(d->control->completer(), 0, this, 0);`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the reason... it seems that it disconnects the completer signals and line edit slots. Why the hack they did this?

Comment: @V.K. probably to disable the completer while the `QLineEdit` doesn't have the focus. But may be, it is not necessary and a bug. (You may report it...) or using a workaround in `MyLineEdit` to re-connect in `focusInEvent()`.

Comment: @V.K. For me, somebody wanted to save effort. Better would have been to track all connections which are done in `focusInEvent()` and disconnecting explicitly these in `focusOutEvent()`. I would consider this as bug... somehow.

Comment: I will use a workaround, fortunately there are several options to work around this. And I think I will report it as a bug. This is very unexpected behavior which takes very long time to discover what is the problem. Thank you for your help.